# I need to get email address of logged in mail?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I have JavaScript Script, which is injected to the browser when i log in to the gmail. How can I get an email adress of current user? what do you think? then I should Open pup up page from another server and she should know that email adress. cant I get from session or something like that?

Comment: This sounds very shady.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Use OpenId flow in a new window and let the user grant you access to their email (this is the proper way).
2. Use JavaScript DOM manipulation (though note there are oddities such as delegated account access or multi-login).

Look for a span such as the following:

```
<span id="gbi4t" style="max-width: 478px; text-align: left;">john@gail.com</span>
```

Comment: the second way is not secure for my. can you give me a lint of the firt way?